# Synopsys Detect task on Azure DevOps CI Pipeline fails with a 404

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, blackduck, synopsis-detect

I'm dealing with a CI pipeline that uses the Synopsys Detect task and suddenly it started to fail. I looked at the logs and this is the output:

[image]

After seeing that I went to the URL where the task tries to get the Detect script from, and this is what's there:

[image]

However, no matter which path you add to the URL, even with no Major number, it returns a 404. This makes me thing that maybe the scripts are no longer available there? I've tried to look online for any related posts but couldn't find anything mentioning this specific error nor anything related to the scripts being removed from that location.

Any input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the task version 6. This was deprecated. You should use the latest task version 8. This will allow you to use the latest script version.

Should start with:

- task: SynopsysDetectTask@8